# bitcoind getmininginfo says hashespersec is 0

Tags: bitcoind, hash, miner-configuration, cpu-mining

I started mining yesterday on a low-end system, trying to figure out how it works.
I used the bincoind build from Debian. When I try
`bitcoind getmininginfo` today, I get the following output.

```
{
    "blocks" : 208085,
    "currentblocksize" : 0,
    "currentblocktx" : 0,
    "difficulty" : 3368767.14053294,
    "errors" : "",
    "generate" : true,
    "genproclimit" : -1,
    "hashespersec" : 0,
    "pooledtx" : 69,
    "testnet" : false
}
```

It looks like hashes per sec is 0. Shouldn't that be some positive number? 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you certain that you are actually mining? What command line did you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hashespersec` field reports the speed of the built-in miner. It does not (and can't accurately) report the hashing power connected to it via the `getwork` or `getblocktemplate` interfaces.

Comment: Does that mean my bitcoind instance is not trying to mine?

Comment: Indeed - it doesn't do that by default, and there is no reason to turn that on either. The internal miner is just there as reference, but is 1) not optimized 2) you shouldn't mine on CPUs anyway.

Comment: I'm doing this for fun rather than profit. How can I get the reference miner to do some work? Need not be significant.

Comment: Start with -gen, or run the RPC command: ./bitcoind setgenerate true. But really, even if you want to do CPU mining, use an external miner program. It'll be a lot faster. Especially as the built-in miner cannot use pools, the result of running it will be a 99.97% chance for having nothing after a month, and a 0.03% chance for 25 BTC.

Comment: Isn't it in the plans to fully deprecate both `-gen` and its related statistics fields?

Comment: @DavidPerry Yes, I suppose that will happen soon.

Comment: I did the rpc call, note the generate attribute is true. So, I expected bitcoind to mine.

Comment: Fine, I'll install a good miner. Any suggestions?