# Can bitcoind still do CPU-based mining or was that feature removed?

Tags: bitcoind, miner-configuration, cpu

I'm seeing conflicting claims about whether  `bitcoind` can still do CPU-based mining. As far back as 2011 people were saying that feature was going to "soon" be removed. Was mining removed?
By the way if mining is removed from `bitcoind`, what are the things it can still do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still there as of version 0.8.5, but just a reference implementation. It's not optimized, doesn't support pooled mining, and is not exposed via the Qt GUI.

To enable, start with the -gen option. But other than testnet (and even there...), it's utterly pointless.

Comment: Is there a miner that supports pooled mining that still uses the CPU? It appears cgminer will not, nor bfgminer.

Comment: I'm mining at about 2 Gh/s at testnet using **setgenerate true 1** the last number is how many cores to use, you can check your hashrate with **hashespersec**

Comment: @Jonas What is testnet? Where is hashespersec?

Comment: If you want to try experimenting you should not do it with real bitcoins, thats where testnet comes in. **bitcoind -testnet** it will create a "testnet3" folder, and will not overwrite your "mainnet" files :-)

Comment: By the way I am periodically getting "error: no response from server". I run "bitcoind -gen &" and then a while later "bitcoind getinfo" and I get this error. Any idea what causes it?

Comment: OK when I run "bitcoind -testnet" and try to getinfo, the error changes to: "error: couldn't connect to server".

Comment: I am running Bitcoin-QT, and enter the commands in the console. Not sure if this answer is up to date http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5841/bitcoind-getmininginfo-says-hashespersec-is-0

Comment: If your running linux try **ps aux | grep bitcoind** that will give you a list of any bitcoind processes

Comment: @JonasOestman Pretty sure that's 2 Mh/s.

Comment: OK, it appears my config file had something in it that was messing things up. I reverted to just rpcuser/pass and now it works. However "bitcoind gethashespersec" is returning a value of 0 when I'm running "bitcoin-qt --server". **However** when I run "bitcoind -gen &" and then gethashespersec I do get 1931863.

Comment: But my question is still not entirely answered. If I run "bitcoind -gen" without testnet, am I actually able to generate bitcoins (even if very slowly), which will end up in my wallet.dat?

Comment: If you find a block (which, with a decent desktop CPU, at the current difficulty, would happen once every ~10000 years), you'll get 25 BTC in your wallet. If you don't, nothing will happen except higher electricity bill, and wear and tear on your computer.

Comment: @Friendly: bfgminer does support it, though you may have to compile from source.  There is a note that the cpu mining support is disabled in some of the binary distributions.

Comment: Update: [The `-gen` option for mining was removed in version 0.13.0](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.13.0#removal-of-internal-miner)

Answer (score 1):

As of version 0.13.0, CPU mining has been removed from Bitcoin Core.

[Since which version the mining functionality removed from wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49664/since-which-version-the-mining-functionality-removed-from-wallet/49696#49696)

Comment: Here's the release note with the corresponding section: [Bitcoin Core 0.13.0 removed the internal mining capability](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.13.0#removal-of-internal-miner)