# Since which version is the mining functionality removed from the wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, litecoin, cpu-mining

As I'm starting to learn to create a new altcoin, I found there is a remarkable difference between old and new Bitcoin/Litecoin Core wallet: old versions (0.6.9 of Litecoin) have mining functionality integrated in the wallet with a tab and a button for it while new versions (from 0.7.0.1 of Bitcoin) don't.

So my question is **from which version is the mining functionality removed from the wallet**? Are there **any change logs/release notes/statements** that tell about this change? And can someone tell me **why we should separate it from the wallet**?

I really want to see if I can re-integrate this functionality back to the wallet as most of my clients are low-tech and a button "Mining" will be definitely much visually easier then running bunch of lines of command in the terminal.

I guess some of you may then start to tell me to stop creating new altcoins but my clients really want to have a new bitcoin-like currency for their private business so I think you will unlikely to see it public elsewhere if you're not part of the business so never mind. :)

Any reference links or articles or kinds of help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcoin Core removed it in version 0.13.0.  You can see the change log at https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.13.0:

> ## Removal of internal miner
>
> As CPU mining has been useless for a long time, the internal miner has been removed in this release, and replaced with a simpler implementation for the test framework.

For future questions like this, all change logs can be found at https://bitcoin.org/en/version-history.

Answer (score 1):

## Removal of internal miner

As CPU mining has been useless for a long time, the internal miner has been removed in this release, and replaced with a simpler implementation for the test framework.

The overall result of this is that `setgenerate` RPC call has been removed, as well as the -gen and -genproclimit command-line options.

For testing, the generate call can still be used to mine a block, and a new RPC call **`generatetoaddress`** has been added to mine to a specific address. This works with wallet disabled.

[More info](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.13.0#removal-of-internal-miner)