# How can I solo mine using Bitcoin Core?

Tags: mining-software

I want to mine Bitcoin using the Bitcoin Core client.

I have followed the steps on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xd4Opw0Upok, but when I type "setgenerate true" in the console, it replies with "Method not found (code -32601)"

How can I mine Bitcoin with Bitcoin Core?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot.  The mining functionality was removed in version 0.13.0 since it was hopelessly inefficient.  See [Since which version the mining functionality removed from wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49664/since-which-version-the-mining-functionality-removed-from-wallet/49696#49696)

It is not practical to mine Bitcoin without recent specialized ASIC hardware.  See [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41276/in-the-asic-age-is-it-worth-starting-mining-bitcoin-at-home)