# How can i mine solo with Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, solo-mining

It's only a question, i don't want to mine solo, knowing that it's not efficient, but since Bitcoin Core 0.13.0 how do we mine solo? (using rpc maybe?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I solo mine using Bitcoin Core?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51169/how-can-i-solo-mine-using-bitcoin-core)

Comment: This topic doesn't answer my question

Comment: Download `cfgminer` or `gpuminer` or...