# RPi3 Mining Node Wallet Address Configuration

Tags: wallet, address, miner-configuration

I am using a RPi3 as a stock bitcoin mining node. I am getting it all set up. I am not expecting to ever actually mine any coin. I am just doing it for fun and learning.

I know that if my node were to mine a block it would create a transaction for the bitcoins that it earns by doing so.

My question is where do I set that public wallet address to receive those coins? I am using a tutorial to set up the software and it doesn't say anything about setting that address.

I have also searched everywhere I can think of and can't find any information on it.

Answer (score 1):

Support for the built-in CPU miner was removed in Bitcoin Core v0.13 (see https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.13.0#removal-of-internal-miner), so this issue is moot.

Historically speaking, the built in miner asked the built-in wallet for an address. So it was not configurable - you just had to use the internal wallet RPC to manage the funds you got out of mining.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any mentions in the docs but traced down in the source, it appears that when the Wallet is generated a dedicated [Miner address is created](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.12/src/wallet/wallet.cpp#L2791) and then the Miner main thread loads the wallet and [uses that address for mining](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.12/src/miner.cpp#L421).

Note: the Mining functionality was [removed in version 0.13.0](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/49696/52446).